# How to best adjust images to a max content width of 490px?

Tags: images, the-content

On a large blog with thousands of images there are posts published by people who do not know much about image optimization.

I am searching for a plugin or even a simple wp_content filter function in order to make all images a maximum width of 490 BEFORE they get downloaded.

Ususally I would usually filter the_content for all image urls and replace em with a timthumb.php URL. However a good Plugin or a newer alternative to timthumb.php would be probably better - do you know a solution? Would be best if it works for internal as well as external images.

Comment: with your reputation you are supposed to know that plugin reccomendations is off-topic :(

Comment: Its actually not a plugin recommendation question. The answer "a plugin is best for this purpose" would be valid. The basic question is - what is the best solution for this problem.

Comment: When the question contains something like "However a good Plugin or a newer alternative to timthumb.php would be probably better" it is a request for plugin or library recommendation and a very valid excuse to close vote questions which don't show effort. so what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

First thing twice about your desired resolutions, then [add some image sizes](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=wordpress%20add%20image%20size), and then i would bulk resize images. There are existing solutions.

With that done, you then could change image urls to point to the shiny new image sizes by filter, as you suggest, or do a [search & replace](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=mysql%20search%20replace%20regex) over the #__posts table. However, be careful with that, better test your expressions before firing it on a thousands of posts.